# What's the connection?

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, tribond

What do Sylvia Plath, Starcraft, and Ico have in common?  This one shouldn't be too hard, but might be.  (And given my record, will anger several people for some apparent reason....)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Commissioner%27s_Office; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ic%C3%B3; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ico, [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think ICO refers to the game, since Sylvia Plath wrote a bunch of love poems and the game had a "boy meets girl" theme. Also starcraft is a game.

Comment: Love poems???  Ha.  Well, she was a poet.

Comment: Nice question! Reminds me of one of my favorite game shows, Only Connect. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're all related to a

> Colossus.

Sylvia Plath

> had a poem called *The Colossus* which was published in a collection called  *The Colossus and other Poems*.

Starcraft

> has a unit called a [Colossus](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Colossus).

Ico

> is a video game that was succeeded by *The Shadow of the Colossus* by the same developers.

Comment: random knowledge or awesome reasearch skills ?

Comment: @Lordofdark I knew about Ico and Sylvia Plath, but had to Google Starcraft.

Comment: I guess I didn't have to say 'Starcraft 2'.  Good answer!